# how to see generated sql from a linq query

Tags: sql, linq

Just trying to get the sql that is generated by a linq query.

Comment: Are you using Linq2Sql or Entity Framework?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework. Is there a way in which, I can understand what SQL command is getting executed for a particular LINQ query ?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, I Linq2Sql.  But a solution with both EF and Linq2Sql, I sure would be wonderful.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With Linq2Sql

```
dc.GetCommand(query).CommandText
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx for more info.

But I usually use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: Thanks, I believe this will work. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 21):

There are 3 ways do that.

1.You can use LINQPad.It's Free http://www.linqpad.net/

2.You can use SQL Server Profiler inside the Sql Server (Tools --> SQL Server Profiler)

3.You can use Visual Studio Debugger for Generate T-Sql.(with any visual studio version)

Answer (score 7):

Use `SQL Profiler` if you are using SQL Server as your database.

Answer (score 4):

This popped up on Google, it's an 8-part tutorial. I think it will keep you busy for a few hours, it seems quite detailed to me.

1: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

2: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx

3: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx

4: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx

5: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx

6: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

7: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx

8: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Another way

From the MSDN article [How to: Display Generated SQL (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx)

Set the [`DataContext.Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) Property to `Console.Out` and you'll see it in the console

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i could suggest is to go with `Database` `Log`. Put `Log`after initializing `DataContext` and you will be able to track whatever is done by EF on visual studio `output` window.

```
  DataContext db = new DataContext();
  db.Database.Log = generatedSQL =>
   {
      Debug.WriteLine(generatedSQL);
   };
```

Comment: this would ve been nice, but Log property is not available in Database. (netcore 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Diagnostic tools*** in Visual Studio to see the generated query.

To enable this, go to top right corner, there you can see **quick search** and type diagnostic tools.

In the results, click on appropriate option and see below for query generated.