# C# - Convert linq query to SQL statements in portable class

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to create a portable class library that supports multi-platforms (Mobile, Desktop, Web)
this library will consume Rest API (ASP API) .. what I want is write LINQ statements in the portable class then convert it to SQL statement as a string then send it to web service 
What I found is [IQToolkit](http://www.cmjackson.net/2010/02/10/using-the-linq-iqueryable-toolkit/) but it needs a database provider to generate the SQL statements .. so any ideas to make this?

**Update:**

My work is this:

```
private IEnumerable<MemberExpression> DevideExpressions(Expression condition)
    {
        var candidates = new Queue<Expression>(new[] { condition });


        while (candidates.Count > 0)
        {
            var expr = candidates.Dequeue();
            if (expr is MemberExpression)
            {
                yield return ((MemberExpression)expr);
            }
            else if (expr is UnaryExpression)
            {

                candidates.Enqueue(((UnaryExpression)expr).Operand);
            }
            else if (expr is BinaryExpression)
            {
                var binary = expr as BinaryExpression;
                candidates.Enqueue(binary.Left);
                candidates.Enqueue(binary.Right);

            }
            else if (expr is MethodCallExpression)
            {
                var method = expr as MethodCallExpression;
                foreach (var argument in method.Arguments)
                {
                    candidates.Enqueue(argument);


                }
            }
            else if (expr is LambdaExpression)
            {
                candidates.Enqueue(((LambdaExpression)expr).Body);

            }
        }

    }
```

so there are two cases:
1- The code is like:

```
var result = MyDb.Select<Users>(f=> f.UserName == "my name");
```

it gives me string result:
"UserName = \"my name\""
so I can handle it to SQL easily

2- The code is like:

```
string name = "my name";
var result = MyDb.Select<Users>(f=> f.UserName == name);
```

It gives me string result:
   "UserName = value(DbEntityWpf.MainWindow).name"

So the main problem that I want to get the value of () as a string at runtime .. if this happened, every thing will be OK .

Comment: IQToolkit was abandoned in 2011. Perhaps [how to convert linq query to sql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6190620/1115360) would be more useful for you.

Comment: Portable class library doesn't have Linq2Sql or Entity framework .. so I can not use these solutions :)