# convert C# Linq to T-Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

i'm a junior developer and trying to convert the following linq statement to T-Sql:

```
    var results = context
      .Employees
      .Where(item => (dateFilter.ToUpper() == "P") ? item.PublishedDate >= From : item.CapturedDate >= dateFromDT)
      .Where(item => (dateFilter.ToUpper() == "P") ? item.PublishedDate <= dateTo : item.CapturedDate <= dateTo)
      .FirstOrDefault()
```

Can one please help me?

```
Select * from Employees where PublishedDate = From and .......
```

Comment: If that's working code already, why not just log what SQL it used?

Comment: i'm actually converting c# api to sql store procedure so i want to convert i'm not quite sure of my where statement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert linq query to sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190620/how-to-convert-linq-query-to-sql)

Comment: Another possible duplicate:  [How to view LINQ generated SQL statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899974/how-to-view-linq-generated-sql-statements). I like the LinqPad suggestion, great tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something similar to this:

```
select top 1 * 
  from employees 
 where (upper(DateFilter) = 'P' and PublishedDate >= From and PublishedDate <= dateTo)
    or (upper(DateFilter) <> 'P' and CapturedDate >= dateFromDT and CapturedDate <= dateTo)
```

if DateFilter is a column in the table then it is better to skip the upper as it can degrade performance (given that you have a index on that column).

Comment: `upper` function won't make any difference here.

Comment: You are correct that upper is not needed unless the server collation is case sensitive (which is not the default).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this.

```
 Select Top 1 * from Employees 
     where 
(dateFilter = "P" COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  AND PublishedDate >= From AND PublishedDate >=dateTo) 
OR 
(dateFilter != "P" COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS AND CapturedDate  >= dateFromDT AND CapturedDate  >= dateTo)
```

Comment: ....Like these ?  `if(@dateFilter)='p'
    begin
      SET @Where='PublishedDate  >= '''+cast(@dateFrom as varchar)+''' AND PublishedDate  >= '''+cast(@dateFrom as varchar)+''''
    end`

Comment: @Clifford : Why you are type casting your `@dateFrom` to `varchar`

Comment: Because i'm passing the date, example 04/5/2017